# og:image being ignored

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Suddenly all of my sites starting to show 3 images to share a link on facebook instead of the one defined in og:image.

linter shows the og:image is defined and i don't have the warning of its dimensions because its size is 200x200px.

for example:

URL: http://alertasaude.com/

Debug: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Falertasaude.com%2F

if you post it on a wall it will show 3 different images (in this case the third one is the one defined on og:image)

Comment: I see only 1 share button on a post page. To the right of the date the message was posted.

Comment: everything's fine with your debugger information. have you fixed the problem in the meantime? if yes, you should delete/close this question.

Comment: having the same issue, my images are much larger than 200px, do it seems to be unrelated to the image size. the page appears ok with the correct image in the facebook debugger, but i see 3 unrelated issues when sharing the page from my timeline.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.  My page had an og:image that was sized under 200px... which I fixed by directing to a compliant version of the image.  Now my Linter data shows correct without errors, but the three-image thing still happens.

Fb used to allow you to get by with a 50x50, but I'm guessing they're changing their requirements, and somehow the Linter data isn't flushing correctly.  Try directing to a 200x200 and cross your finger that it gets fixed in the next crawl.

Comment: anyone found a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Everything was ok a few weeks ago even with more than 3 images.

What I did, trying to fix this recent issue, is create 5 images with all same dimensions 500x300, paste and adjust photo inside. then create og:image tag with different names.

Linter recognize all images (no error) an d create thumbnails.
But when sharing the page in facebook, I get only 3 thumbnails.
If I reorder images in the html code, and check in linter again, I get the same issue with different images.
I also tried to change filenames (with -, _, digits and letters only)
I did that 5 or 6 times in a row with the same result.

Does anynone have a solution?